# rsync: failed to set times on "/cygdrive/e/.": Invalid argument (22)

Tags: windows, rsync, usb-drive

I get the below error message when I try to rsync from a local hard disk to a USB disk mounted at E: on Windows 10.

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/cygdrive/e/.": Invalid argument (22)
```

My rsync command is as below (path shortened for brevity):

```
rsync -rtv --delete --progress --modify-window=5 /cygdrive/d/path/to/folder/ /cygdrive/e/
```

I actually need to set modification times (on directories as well) and rsync actually sets modification times perfectly. It only fails to set times on root of the USB disk.

Comment: OK so using option `-O` / `--omit-dir-times` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/668049/6730571) is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: It is not acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced exactly the same problem.

1. I created a dir containing one text file and when trying to *rsync* it to an removable (*USB*) drive, I got the error. However, the file **was copied** to the destination. The problem is not reproducible if the destination is a folder (other than *root*) on the removable drive
2. I then repeated the process using a fixed drive as destination, and the problem was not reproducible

The 1<sup>st</sup> difference that popped up between the 2 drives, was the *file system* (for more details, check [[MS.Docs]: File Systems Technologies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc778296(v=ws.10))):

- *FAT32* - on the removable drive
- *NTFS* - on the fixed one

So this was the cause of my failure. Formatting the *USB* drive as *NTFS* fixed the problem:

1. The *USB* drive formatted as *FAT32* (default):

   > ```bash
   > cfati@cfati-e5550-0 /cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q045006385
   > $ ll /cygdrive/
   > total 20
   > dr-xr-xr-x  1 cfati                       None                        0 Jul 14 17:58 .
   > drwxrwx---+ 1 cfati                       None                        0 Jun  9 15:04 ..
   > d---r-x---+ 1 NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller 0 Jul 13 22:21 c
   > drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM                      SYSTEM                      0 Jul 14 13:19 e
   > drwxr-xr-x  1 cfati                       None                        0 Dec 31  1979 n
   > drwxr-xr-x  1 cfati                       None                        0 Dec 31  1979 w
   >
   > cfati@cfati-e5550-0 /cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q045006385
   > $ rsync -rtv --progress --modify-window=5 ./dir/ /cygdrive/w
   > sending incremental file list
   > rsync: failed to set times on "/cygdrive/w/.": Invalid argument (22)
   > ./
   > a.txt
   >               3 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/2)
   >
   > sent 111 bytes  received 111 bytes  444.00 bytes/sec
   > total size is 3  speedup is 0.01
   > rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
   >
   > cfati@cfati-e5550-0 /cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q045006385
   > $ ll /cygdrive/
   > total 20
   > dr-xr-xr-x  1 cfati                       None                        0 Jul 14 17:58 .
   > drwxrwx---+ 1 cfati                       None                        0 Jun  9 15:04 ..
   > d---r-x---+ 1 NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller 0 Jul 13 22:21 c
   > drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM                      SYSTEM                      0 Jul 14 13:19 e
   > drwxr-xr-x  1 cfati                       None                        0 Dec 31  1979 n
   > drwxr-xr-x  1 cfati                       None                        0 Dec 31  1979 w
   > ```
2. After formatting the *USB* drive as *NTFS*:

   > ```bash
   > cfati@cfati-e5550-0 /cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q045006385
   > $ ll /cygdrive/
   > total 24
   > dr-xr-xr-x  1 cfati                       None                        0 Jul 14 17:59 .
   > drwxrwx---+ 1 cfati                       None                        0 Jun  9 15:04 ..
   > d---r-x---+ 1 NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller 0 Jul 13 22:21 c
   > drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM                      SYSTEM                      0 Jul 14 13:19 e
   > drwxr-xr-x  1 cfati                       None                        0 Dec 31  1979 n
   > drwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators              Administrators              0 Jul 14 17:59 w
   >
   > cfati@cfati-e5550-0 /cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q045006385
   > $ rsync -rtv --progress --modify-window=5 ./dir/ /cygdrive/w
   > sending incremental file list
   > ./
   > a.txt
   >               3 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/2)
   >
   > sent 111 bytes  received 38 bytes  298.00 bytes/sec
   > total size is 3  speedup is 0.02
   >
   > cfati@cfati-e5550-0 /cygdrive/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q045006385
   > $ ll /cygdrive/
   > total 24
   > dr-xr-xr-x  1 cfati                       None                        0 Jul 14 17:59 .
   > drwxrwx---+ 1 cfati                       None                        0 Jun  9 15:04 ..
   > d---r-x---+ 1 NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller NT SERVICE+TrustedInstaller 0 Jul 13 22:21 c
   > drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM                      SYSTEM                      0 Jul 14 13:19 e
   > drwxr-xr-x  1 cfati                       None                        0 Dec 31  1979 n
   > drwxrwxrwx+ 1 Administrators              Administrators              0 Jul 14 13:19 w
   > ```

As a side note, when I was at step ***#2.***, I was an idiot and kept the *--delete* arg, so til I hit <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>, it deleted some data. Luckily, it didn't get to delete crucial files / folders.

Comment: I had troubles to use `rsync` to backup on an external usb  device, the problem was related to the `NTFS` causing the error `rsync: mkstemp failed: Invalid argument (22)`, changing the filesystem to `ext4` fixed the issue